# Query regarding Statsd and Collectd

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, graphite, statsd, collectd

I have a query regarding the usage of statsd and collectd.

Wherever I see in the internet, I am only getting examples where **statsd/collectd** is used to collect metric information about the Application/System.

My Question is: Can statsd/collectd be used to collect statistical information on any other datasets which is not a system performance related data Eg: in Ecommerce,?

Can we use it to get the information of top 10 or top 15 users / URLs that are hitting the website, in a time-series analysis(say in last 15 minutes or last 15 days)?

Any relevant links or document in this regards is most welcome.

Also, I wanted to know if we can store this data in Elastic Search as well. Any documents on this is also most relevant to me and most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I found this document  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-statsd-to-collect-arbitrary-stats-for-graphite-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: This sounds like a perfect job for logstash, elasticseach and kibana. If you collect your webserver logs and process them with logstash, saving them in to elasticsearch you should have this information at your fingertips

Comment: @Rumbles, thanks I also found this out , My doubt is that If I index One days Logs into One Index, (eg: logstash-12-12-2016) and next days data into another single Index( logstatsh-13-12-2016). And Keep on doing this for 2 Months (i.e. I will end up with 60 indexes...). Each Index contains arround 10 Million Records..  Hence While Creating Visualizations, in Kibana, will It face any performance Issue, to query from 60 indexes and plot graph accross multiple days...???

Comment: There would be performance issues depending on the power of the machines running your elasticsearch cluster, the amount of memory and speed of disks